# Is there a way to search just for the first coordinate in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Assuming I have a list of tuples like the following:
`a = [('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('e','f')]`
If I were to execute this line `'a' in a` I would get `False`.
Is there a way to tell python "search the just for the first argument and accept whatever in the second"?
So that I could search something like `('a', *) in a` and get `True`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `any` (will return `True` if any of the elements is logically `True`) with `map` (to compare each first element in your tuples):

```
any(map(lambda x: x[0] == "a", a)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it will list comprehension

```
a = [('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('e','f')]
'a' in [i[0] for i in a]
```

Or for larger search

```
'a' in {i[0] for i in a}
```

since finding an item in a set is way faster.
Both exprations will return

```
True
```

Comment: `'a' in [i[0]` will return true also for `aaaa`.

Comment: `'a' in ['aaa']` will return False